# MKStoreKit Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product:

Tags: xcode, itunes

I'm trying to configure the MKStoreKit 5 plugin.
But I got this message when the application starts.

Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: com.website.app.feature1
Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: com.website.app.feature2

My Bundle name ID is exactly the same in Itunes connect and in the project properties.

I also added 2 In App purchases (Non-Consumable) on Itunes connect with this product ID:

com.website.app.feature1
AND I also tried
feature2

These 2 in app purchases are also on the MKStoreKitConfigs.plist file.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Consumables</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>Non-Consumables</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.website.app.feature1</string>
        <string>com.website.app.feature2</string>
    </array>
    <key>Subscriptions</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I can't find any updated tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Just wait. The In App purchase can take few hours to be available.